# How do I create json file from plist file?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, json, plist

I want to create a json file from from existing plist file. How do I create json file from plist file using one of these programming languages: Javascript or Java or Objective-c or Python or Ruby?

Comment: I am not sure if any plist could be expressed as a JASON file, what plist exactly you want to convert?

Answer (score 12):

Python has a module [plistlib](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/plistlib.html) which you can use to read plist files. plistlib is available in python >= 2.6, so if you have old version you can get plistlib from [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/plistlib.py).

After reading plist as dict using `plistlib.readPlist` you can dump it as JSON using `json.dumps`, for that use [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module or for old python version get [simplejson](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)

Here is an example:

```
plist = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aDict</key>
    <dict>
        <key>anotherString</key>
        <string>&lt;hello hi there!&gt;</string>
    </dict>
    <key>aList</key>
    <array>
        <string>A</string>
        <string>B</string>
        <integer>12</integer>
        <real>32.100000000000001</real>
        <array>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </array>
    </array>
    <key>aString</key>
    <string>Doodah</string>
</dict>
</plist>
"""

import json
from plistlib import readPlist
import StringIO

in_file = StringIO.StringIO(plist)
plist_dict = readPlist(in_file)

print json.dumps(plist_dict)
```

Output:

```
{"aList": ["A", "B", 12, 32.100000000000001, [1, 2, 3]], "aDict": {"anotherString": "<hello hi there!>"}, "aString": "Doodah"}
```

Answer (score 7):

On OSX you can use the plutil command line tool:

```
plutil -convert json Data.plist
```

It isn't using one of those languages, but it saves you from implementing it yourself or messing with libraries.

Comment: `plutil -convert json Data.plist -e json` makes sure it doesn't overwrite the original file and creates a new file with the same name but with the .json extension

Comment: Sadly, even as of Monterey, this utility fails too often to be of general use.

Answer (score 3):

Load the property list and get a dictionary out of it. Then using one of the many JSON frameworks, initialize a store-like object (an object that takes a dictionary as input) and write that out to a file. Should create your JSON just fine.